# Bamboo Agent Monitoring

Tags: bamboo

We have one Bamboo master server, and more than 20 Linux Bamboo agents are connected to it. We would like to monitor those agents as soon as they go offline.

Is there a way we can monitor the agent state using the SHELL script and have the system send the notification over email as soon as any agent goes offline or becomes online?